# Can't understand the way python's function signatures are documented

Tags: python

I'm a beginner in Python and when I read its documentation I just can't seem to understand the way some functions' signatures are documented. For example, range(start, stop[, step]), I don't understand the meaning of putting step in a bracket like that. Is it because the argument is optional?

Comment: it means indeed that `step` is an optional argument (i.e. there is a default value for it. `1` in this case).

Comment: [Guide to reading python documentation](https://www.biostars.org/p/16683/)

Comment: `range` is a trickier to use than the signature lets on.  Read the whole docs, and play around with it.  Rember you want use `list( range(10))` to see an actual list.  But. yes, in general brackets means optional.  But there are also optional keyword arguments.